# Compare each pair of list in multiple lists to create an order list

Tags: python, compare

```
a_list = [[70,62],[31,62],[62,71],[70,31],[70,71],[31,71]]
```

I have a list above. Each list above has two elements, the first element is always less than the second element(e.x: 30 < 62 for first list) - I don't compare the numbers themselves (of course 30 <62 but if the list is (62,30) so it should be 62 <30). So based on the list I have, how can I make a whole list of order in efficient way? I try to write manually but my code runs so wrongly with many if statements

The result should be:

```
[70,31,62,71]
```

after comparing each pair of each list.

I tried with 3 pairs of list as belows:

```
sort = []
list = [[48, 33], [56, 33], [56, 48]]
for i in list[:-1]:
   for j in list[1:]:
       if i[0] == j[1]:
           sort.extend([i[0],i[1],j[0]])
           break
print(sort)
```

The result is [56,48,33]
But for larger numbers, I am still checking.

Comment: where is your o so slow code?

Comment: You want a faster solution, but what do you mean by "faster", when you haven't shown your own solution?

Comment: and why it the 71 in your result?

Comment: Don't name lists `list`

Comment: and dont name them `dict` or `set` either

Comment: As I understand it, the OP doesn't want to sort numbers, but objects who aren't  necessarily  directly comparable, and each [a, b] list means that a < b. From that, she is supposed to order all of the objects. @Tina, is this what you mean?

Comment: oh sorry. I make my code really a mess now and it doesn't give the right result as I expect. I will edit above post. My idea is compare 2 pairs of lists, so many if statement.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille in each pair, the first element should be ordered before the second element. That's what I mean. For example, (a,b) -> when I put them in a whole list, a should stay before b.

Comment: @Tina Your edit seems wrong (if I understand the question correctly). Shouldn't the order be `[56, 48, 33]`? The pair `[56, 48]`, doesn't that mean that `56 < 48`? If so, I think my solution code is giving the correct output.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce sorry, I have changed it. The above code gives the right result, just my writing was wrong. Just edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
... from operator import itemgetter
... 
... 
... def solution(pairs_list):
...     d = defaultdict(int)
...     for a, b in pairs_list:
...         d[a]
...         d[b] += 1
... 
...     return [k for k, _ in sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))]
... 
>>> a_list = [[70, 62], [31, 62], [62, 71], [70, 31], [70, 71], [31, 71]]
>>> solution(a_list)
[70, 31, 62, 71]
>>> b_list = [[48, 33], [56, 33], [56, 48]]
>>> solution(b_list)
[56, 48, 33]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it now. I also try to write for 3 pairs of list. Post now on my code :)

Comment: yes your code works perfect. Can you tell me key = itemgetter(1) gives the default b always stays after a right?

Comment: @Tina I'm sorry I don't fully understand your question. The `defaultdict` called `d` is holding key/value pairs which correspond to how many numbers a particular key is greater than. The pairs for `b_list` would look like: `((56, 0), (48, 1), (33, 2))`. Using `itemgetter(1)` as the sorting key just compares those pairs by the second index, `1`, of each tuple.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I got it. This is the first time I have used itemgetter or defaultdict. I learn something new :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are expressing is a Directed Graph.  You can use the [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/) library to work with these like:

#### Code:

```
def sort_nodes(node_list):
    import networkx as nx
    graph = nx.DiGraph(node_list)
    sorted_nodes = [y[1] for y in sorted(
        (len(neighbors), node) for node, neighbors in graph.pred.items())]
    return sorted_nodes
```

#### Test Code:

```
test_data = (
    dict(
        input=[[70, 62], [31, 62], [62, 71], [70, 31], [70, 71], [31, 71]],
        desired_result=[70, 31, 62, 71]),
    dict(
        input=[[48, 33], [56, 33], [56, 48]],
        desired_result=[56, 48, 33]),
)

import networkx as nx
for test in test_data:
    nodes = sort_nodes(test['input'])
    print(nodes)
    assert nodes == test['desired_result']
```

#### Results:

```
[70, 31, 62, 71]
[56, 48, 33]
```

Comment: Why does `sorted` need to be wrapped with `list`?

Comment: `sum(a_list, [])` is an anti-pattern. *do not use `sum` to flatten a list* (or tuples, or to concatenate strings, etc). You've now created quadratic behavior simply to flatten a list, when all you need is linear behavior.

Comment: `sorted(set(it.chain(*lst)))`

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce, why would you want to * expand instead `from_iterable`?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my idea. The list is not sorted based on the numbers themselves but based on the index they are in each pair of list. For example I have a pair (70,62). When I put them together, 70 should stay before 62 in a new list.

Comment: Yes it works really well. networkx really works well, the code is more convenient. Thanks for your suggestion. But I can't upvote you :(